# How do I delay a z-index change on hover until after a transition?

Tags: css, html

I have a web page containing 3 images. When I hover over my mouse on any of the image, its width and height increase and z-index changes(it comes on top of other images). The problem is that as soon as I move my mouse out of the image div, its z-index changes immediately i.e the other two images gets on top. I want the image to be on top both when it is increasing in size and when it is decreasing in size. 
Here is my CSS:

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: width 2s, height 2s;
}
div.image1 {
    top: 10px;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    content:url("http://freedwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/4-Nature+Wallpapers+2014-1.jpg");
}
div.image2 {
    top: 120px;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    content:url("http://stylonica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/nature.jpg");
}
div.image3 {
    top: 230px;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    content:url("http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/2/748315-beautiful-nature-wallpaper.jpg");
}
div:hover {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Please also include your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <style>
      div {
       position: fixed;
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       transition: z-index 2s, width 2s, height 2s;
      }
      .image1, .image2, .image3{
       z-index: 1;
      }
      div.image1 {
       top: 10px;
       transition-timing-function: linear;
       content:url("http://freedwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/4-Nature+Wallpapers+2014-1.jpg");
      }
      div.image2 {
       top: 120px;
       transition-timing-function: linear;
       content:url("http://stylonica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/nature.jpg");
      }
      div.image3 {
       top: 230px;
       transition-timing-function: linear;
       content:url("http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/2/748315-beautiful-nature-wallpaper.jpg");
      }
      div:hover {
       z-index: 10;
       width: 800px;
       height: 800px;
      }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div class="image1"></div>
      <div class="image2"></div>
      <div class="image3"></div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi, Kostadin! Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you have a working piece of code but the op (and other visitors) may not understand why it works. Adding an explanation would increase your chances of this getting chosen as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

1) Add the `transition: all 2s` rule to the `div:hover` class as well.

2) You haven't explicitly stated `z-index=0` in the `div` class.

3) Plus, you've missed out animating your `z-index` in the `div` class as well, which is why I prefer the `transition: all 2s;`style.

Comment: You can't animate `z-index`. The appearance can be faked, but `z-index` itself is not animate-able or transition-able.

Comment: @TylerH Please explain how this works, then?
http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/gboJf

Comment: @BDawg Please read the first phrase of my second sentence. That is not animating z-index. It is faking the appearance of z-index being animated. Admittedly, my terminology wasn't the best; by "not transition-able", I mean it can't undergo some smooth, continuous process like other animations. It can be stepped through with a switch in values, but that's just faking the appearance of animation.

Comment: @TylerH IT works exactly the same as other animations: values (in a specific unit) is step-wise increased or decreased. This works perfectly for opacity, positions and - yes - z-index. It isn't *faking* anything, but it's rather the other way around. It *can't* fake a fade-in effect because as soon as it changes a layer it is on that layer without any alpha layer changes.

Comment: @BramVanroy position is *definitely* not animate-able, sorry. Not sure what you're talking about. It just seems we are defining the word "animate" differently.

Comment: Okay, folks. This is just a war over words. (Sorry to be the one to start it, @TylerH) You can use z-index in CSS animation/transitions, but the visual effect isn't gradual. That's what he was getting at.

Comment: @TylerH Note that I used *positions*, not *position*. Meaning `left`, `right` and the sorts.

Comment: @BramVanroy you don't need to fake a fade-in effect. Look at the positioning and div sizes. As long as z-index remains > 0 the enlarged image will remain above the others. z-index will only become 0 the moment the image returns to normal size, which works just fine because there's no overlap then.

Comment: I wasn't commenting on the question, only on TylerH's comment that z-index isn't animatable, which it obviously is. Though we all know what he was getting at, I thought it appropriate to clarify what z-index can do.